# Are include guards considered defined after the #define directive or after the #endif directive

Tags: c++, header, include-guards, pre-compilation

I have a circular inclusion considering these files:

fileA.hh

```
#ifndef FILEA_H
#define FILEA_H

#include "fileB.hh"

// Use a function in fileB

#endif
```

fileB.hh

```
#ifndef FILEB_H
#define FILEB_H

#include "fileA.hh"

// use an enum in fileA

#endif
```

I managed to resolve the issue by creating a fileA.cc in which I would include both fileA.hh and fileB.hh, and I removed the inclusion of fileB.hh in fileA.hh. All good.

But that got me thinking, why is my example resulting in a circular inclusion ? If I copy paste fileB.hh in fileA.hh, I should have something like this:

```
#ifndef FILEA_H
#define FILEA_H

#ifndef FILEB_H
#define FILEB_H

#ifndef FILEA_H
#define FILEA_H

// Use a function in fileB

#endif

// use an enum in fileA

#endif

// Use a function in fileB

#endif
```

When I encounter the second `#ifndef FILEA_H` shouldn't it be already defined just above ? Or does that mean that FILEA_H is really defined only after the `#endif` and not only after the `#define` ? How does it work exactly ?

Comment: "When I encounter the second #ifndef FILEA_H shouldn't it be already defined just above ?" Yes, it is. And therefore everything between the second `#ifndef FILEA_H` and the enclosing `#endif` is omitted. Meaning that by the time you reach "use an enum in fileA", you're trying to do so without having the definitions from fileA.hh visible. It stops the mutual includes from being an infinite descent where A includes B which includes A which includes B which includes A which... but it doesn't stop the issue you were experiencing.

Comment: [Related reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: Pretty much Mandatory reading in this case.

Comment: My question is why would you have a circular dependency in the first place. Design that out!

Comment: To answer the question in the title, `#define FILEA_H` defines the name `FILEA_H` when the compiler sees it. There's no special treatment just because it's part of the idiom of an include guard.